# How to create an anchor tag with an img tag inside

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to recreate an element like this:

```
 <a href='https://www.myapp.com/'><img class='footer-img' src="{% static 'assets/banner/ADB_SOF-01.jpg' %}"></a>
```

I have this so far, but not sure where to go with adding the `img` tag inside it.

```
var $a = $("<a>", {href: value.url});
$("#banner").append($a)
```

Comment: What is banner?

Comment: banner is the div I'm trying to append to.

Comment: So create an image and append it to the anchor....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `append` to include the `img`:

```
var $a = $("<a>", {href: value.url}).append(
    $("<img>", {src: "{% static 'assets/banner/ADB_SOF-01.jpg' %}"})
);
```